# Blueprint and factory pattern work together?

Tags: python, rest, flask, blueprint, flask-restful

I am working on a restful service using flask-restful, and I want to leverage both factory pattern and blueprint in my project.
in `app/__init__.py` I have a `create_app` function to create a flask app and return it to outside caller, so the caller can start the app.

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('app.appconfig.DevelopmentConfig')
    from app.resource import resource
    app.register_blueprint(v1, url_prefix='/api')
    print app.url_map
    return app
```

Inside that function I intended to register a blueprint pointing to the implementation package with a prefix url.

In `app/resource/__init__.py` there is the following code:

```
from flask import current_app, Blueprint, render_template
from flask.ext import restful
resource = Blueprint('resource', __name__, url_prefix='/api')

@resource.route('/')
def index():    
    api = restful.Api(current_app)
    from resource.HelloWorld import HelloWorld
    api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/hello')
```

My goal is that I can access the HelloWorld rest service at url `/api/hello`, but I know the above code has something wrong at part of `@resource.route('/') ...`. I got some error like `AssertionError: A setup function was called after the first request was handled.  This usually indicates a bug in the app ...` at `api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/hello')`.
Could you please give me some hints on the correct approach?

Comment: I guess i should add some endpoint s, but i don't know how to direct rest resource requests to desired endpoint ...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Flask-Restful, like all properly implemented Flask extensions, supports two methods of registering itself:

1. With the app at instantiation (as you are trying to do with `Api(current_app)`)
2. At a later point using [`api.init_app(app)`](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#flask.ext.restful.Api.init_app)

The canonical way of dealing with the circular imports issue is to use the second pattern and import the instantiated extension in your `create_app` function and register the extension using the `init_app` method:

```
# app/resource/__init__.py
from resource.hello_world import HelloWorld

api = restful.Api(prefix='/api/v1')  # Note, no app
api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/hello')

# We could actually register our API on a blueprint
# and then import and register the blueprint as normal
# but that's an alternate we will leave for another day
# bp = Blueprint('resource', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
# api.init_app(bp)
```

And then in your `create_app` call you would simply load and register the api:

```
def create_app():
    # ... snip ...
    # We import our extension
    # and register it with our application
    # without any circular references
    # Our handlers can use `current_app`, as you already know
    from app.resource import api
    api.init_app(app)
```

Comment: I got exception **attributeerror: 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'config'** at `self.app.config.get("ERROR_404_HELP", True)` from flask_restful package when calling `abort(404)` in a resource. So i switch to blueprint basing on your above comments, which resolved the issue perfectly, thank you!

Comment: I call my blueprints, after I register my extensions, so I wont have the blueprint setup before I call init_app, is this wrong?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're describing, but creating the blueprints after registering extensions is certainly not wrong.

Comment: It's may be obvious to experienced flask / web developers, but it took me days to finally come upon this. Thank you for the useful pattern.